# How to solve "The border attribute is obsolete. Consider specifying img { border: 0; } in CSS instead"

Tags: attributes, border, obsolete

I am using an image in my website and the html code for this is as follows,

```
<img title="Product-Shot.co.uk Logo" src="images/psuk_logo.png" alt="Product-Shot.co.uk" border="0" />
```

When I try to validate my page using w3 validation, it gives me the following warning,

Line 57, Column 105: The border attribute is obsolete. Consider specifying img { border: 0; } in CSS instead.

I am using Joomla 2.5

I wonder how to get rid of the warning?

Any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Amend your html code to the following or similar:

```
<img style="border: none;" title="Product-Shot.co.uk Logo" src="images/psuk_logo.png" alt="Product-Shot.co.uk" />
```

Actually, "border: none;" is probably the default anyway so you can likely get away with this:

```
<img title="Product-Shot.co.uk Logo" src="images/psuk_logo.png" alt="Product-Shot.co.uk" />
```